# Ajax to validate form $_FILES['ImageFile']

Tags: java, php, ajax, forms

Hey guys i been trying all day to find a way to validate some upload files using javascript

```
// get values from FORM
        var firstname = $("input#firstname").val();
        var lastname = $("input#lastname").val();
        var username = $("input#username").val();
        var ImageFile= $("file#ImageFile").val();
        var email = $("input#email").val();
        var message = $("textarea#message").val();
        var firstName = name; 
        if (firstName.indexOf(' ') >= 0) {
            firstName = name.split(' ').slice(0, -1).join(' ');
        }
        $.ajax({
            url: "mail/contact_me.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                firstname: firstname,
                lastname: lastname,
                username: username,
                ImageFile: ImageFile,
                email: email,
                message: message
            },
            cache: false,
```

If i remove the `var ImageFILE = $("file#ImageFile").val();` the script work i need this to send a attachment with `phpmailer` my php is working my form is working great but if i try adding the java just die i think im doing something wrong here i never was really good on java any subjection?

The email is sent but the attachment is not getting there

Comment: What do you mean by validate? what are you trying to achieve? Btw, this is Javascript. Not Java.

Comment: thanks for the correction  im trying to send a attachment with phpmailer and using this values to POST over the php code but i having problems getting the values for var ImageFile = $("file#ImageFile").val(); im not sure if thats is correct or im doing it wrong

Comment: If anything, that line would only return the image name. It's much easier to post an image without ajax, but if you wish to stick with it, I would suggest searching for a jQuery plugin to handle it for you. http://www.sitepoint.com/10-jquery-ajax-file-uploader-plugins/

Comment: Can you clarify your statement " my php is working my form is working great but if i try adding the java just die i think im doing something wrong here i never was really good on java any subjection"  What issue you are facing ?

Comment: my issue is that The email is sent but the attachment is not getting there  my php dont get the POST file

Comment: @iautomation actually im uploading the image first to my server using php and is working  if i use my form->php but when i add the JS the file is not getting to the php  form->JS->php i think my var ImageFile = $("file#ImageFile").val(); is wrong